# SublimeLinter ignore_match not working when extension is specified

Tags: json, sublimetext3, sublimetext, htmltidy, sublimelinter

I'm trying to get **SublimeLinter** and **HTMLTidy** to ignore certain php warnings. Specifically the  `missing <!DOCTYPE> declaration`, `inserting implicit <body>`, and `inserting missing 'title' element`. It tells you right in the docs how to do this:

```
{
"ignore_match": [
    "missing <!DOCTYPE> declaration",
    "inserting (?:implicit <body>|missing 'title' element)"
    ]
}
```

Source: [Linter Settings](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/linter_settings.html#ignore-match)

Adding that to my SublimeLinter user settings file worked fine. The problem is that I want it only to apply to PHP files, because using just the above will also ignore it on HTML files.

The docs have an example for applying `ignore_match` only to certain extensions:

```
{
"ignore_match": {
    "inc": [
        "missing <!DOCTYPE> declaration",
        "inserting (?:implicit <body>|missing 'title' element)"
        ]
}
```

So I copied that and changed the `inc` to `php` and I still get those warnings on php files.

Here is what the `htmltidy` section of my SublimeLinter settings file looks like:

```
"htmltidy": {
            "@disable": false,
            "args": [],
            "excludes": [],
            "ignore_match": {
                "php": [
                    "missing <!DOCTYPE> declaration",
                    "inserting (?:implicit <body>|missing 'title' element)"
                ]
            }
        }
```

Any idea why `ignore_match` works as it is supposed to until I specify an extension that the `ignore_match` rule is supposed to apply to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is SublimeLinter bug. The settings tokenizer allows to replace tokens like `${project}` or `${home}` in settings. It tries to do it recursively but mess up when you use nested list inside `ignore_match` dictionary.

I've tested it and it changes all strings, wraps it to list and assigns the list name as key to dictionary, so:

`{"ignore_match": { "php": ["Error1", "Error2"]}}`

is converted to:
`{"ignore_match": None, "php": ["Error1","Error2"]}}`

It's quite hard to debug what is going on so I have to recommend saving ignore_match settings before tokenizing and reset after it tokenize. Something like that in lint/linter.py `get_merged_settings`:

```
ims = None
if 'ignore_match' in settings.keys():
    ims = settings['ignore_match']
    del settings['ignore_match']
self.replace_settings_tokens(settings)
if ims:
    settings['ignore_match'] = ims
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I am trying to test it but am not sure where in the `get_merged_settings` function I should place the code you provided. Do I want to place that first, right before `window = self.view.window()`?

Comment: self.replace_settings_tokens(settings)  is original code, kursy replace that with the code above which protects ignore_match entry

Comment: Thanks again! I'm giving you the bounty before I can test it since time is running out. Much appreciated.

Comment: This seems to make `ignore_match` function like it's supposed to. Thank you very much for your time and effort!

Comment: @alkuzad you should consider making a pull request with your changes. :)

Comment: @grotewold this is a hack, you should fix the recursion to make it possible to use nested dictionaries instead of merging that :)

Comment: @grotewold pull request added https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter3/pull/393